# How to create a new column that defines occurrences of a chronological segment in a column using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has a column with numbers in chronological order, such as "Event Number". I want to generate a new column called "Event", where I would like to find the minimum number, "1" and count until it finds the maximun number "34", name that cycle 1. Find the next minimum number "1", count until it finds the maximun number "37", name that cycle 2.

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|      Event Number  |     Event        |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          1         |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          1         |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          2         |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          3         |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          3         |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         ...        |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          34        |         Cycle 1  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          1         |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          2         |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          2         |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          3         |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         ...        |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          37        |         Cycle 2  |
|--------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Basically you just want to iterate over rows, and `if currentEventNumber < previousEventNumber`, increment the `CycleNumber`.

Comment: @Junuxx yes, I am using pandas